How to create a folder with 5 sub folders in Sharepoint without code?
I am trying to organise my project folders and I want a way in which I could open a folder and it automatically creates 5 folders each inside named A,B,C,D,E everything.
Can this be done in share point without code or minimal code?

You want to automate without difficulty, this does not happen.
SharePoint is a difficult product, nothing is simple there.

I've tried using cmd but I'm having to make multiple commands and rename again and again to make it happen. If not share point then can I do it anywhere else?

@PriJain check my below answer you can use power automate to achieve your requirements

Try to Powershell:
Here is the PowerShell code snippet for creating Folders and Sub-Folders inside SharePoint List or Library:
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue)) 
{ 
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
}
  
#Get the Web
$web=Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.company.com"
#Get the List/Library
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("SalesList")
 
If($list)  #Check If List exists!
{
    #Check Folder Doesn't exists in the Library!
    $folder = $list.ParentWeb.GetFolder($list.RootFolder.Url + "/" +"Sales List");
    #sharepoint powershell check if folder exists
    If($folder.Exists -eq $false)
    {
       #Create a Folder
       $folder = $list.AddItem([string]::Empty, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "Sales Sub-Item")
       $folder.Update();
    }
    
    #Create a Sub-Folder "APAC Sales Documents" inside "Sales Documents"    
    $Subfolder = $list.ParentWeb.GetFolder($folder.URL + "/" + "APAC Sales Documents");
     
    #Check if sub-folder doesn't exist already
    If ($Subfolder.Exists -eq $false)
    {
       #Create a Sub-Folder Inside "Sales Documents"
       $Subfolder = $list.AddItem($folder.URL, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "APAC Sales Documents")
       $Subfolder.Update();
    }
}

How about ensuring a nested folder structure in SharePoint Library? E.g. Library/FolderA/FolderAA/FolderAAA
#Get the Web
$web=Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.company.com"
 
#Get the List/Library
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents")
 
#Function to Ensure FolderPath
Function Ensure-FolderPath($FolderPath)
{
    $SubFolders = $FolderPath -split "/"
    $RootFolder =  $SubFolders[0]
    $SubfolderPath = $RootFolder
 
    For($i =1; $i -le $SubFolders.count-1; $i++)
    {        
        $SubfolderPath = $SubfolderPath+"/"+$SubFolders[$i]
        $Folder = $Web.GetFolder($SubfolderPath)
 
        #Create Folder if it doesn't exists
        If($Folder.Exists -eq $false)
        {
            $TargetFolder = $Web.Folders.Add($SubfolderPath)
            Write-host "Folder Created:"$SubfolderPath
        }
    }
}


@PriJain you can use power automate, you can trigger it when you create a main folder, then inside the flow you can define to create the sub-folders using this action:-

I have done this in a lot of projects
